# How Do I Determine the Distribution and Version of Linux Using PowerShell 6.x or Newer?

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-core

Using a PowerShell script in PowerShell 6.x or newer, running on an unknown Linux distribution, how do I programmatically and reliably determine the distribution and version number of the operating system?

Edit:
Maybe something like this answer, plus some string-parsing?:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6348

Comment: You should use the `lsb_release` program if it's available, and the contents of `/etc/os-release` otherwise.  How you'd do that in PowerShell is beyond me.  Do note that the version need not be numeric, such as for Debian testing and unstable.

Comment: What linux distribution? You could run bash in powershell with `bash -c "lsb_release -a"` if using LSB(Linux Standard Base). Otherwise you could run `bash -c "cat /etc/*-release"`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this as well inside a powershell script. I use the following solution:

```
$distribution = Invoke-Expression "lsb_release -cs"
```

This makes `$distribution` contain the, for example, following value:

```
bionic
```

You can do the same for the version:

```
$version = Invoke-Expression "lsb_release -rs"
```

This makes `$version` contain the, for example, following value:

```
18.04
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the distro and version number.

```
$release = Invoke-Expression "(lsb_release -ds || cat /etc/*release || uname -om) 2>/dev/null | head -n1"
```

`$release` will contain something like `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS` or `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`.

If you're like me and just needed the distro, you can then use Regex to capture.

```
$release | grep -Po '^[^\s]+'
```

`$release` will contain something like `Ubuntu` or `CentOS`.